# Remote computing

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, teamviewer

How can I remote login from an Ubuntu machine via an another Ubuntu machine to get the maximum speed? I tried to use TeamViewer, but it's very slow. VNC also has issues. Please let me know about which software to use and the process to use it.

Comment: Take a look at Remmina, installed by default. If you use Chrome, you can use Chrome Remote Desktop

Answer (score 0):

Run ssh server (`openssh-server` package) on the machine and then remote login without GUI using `ssh` command. The performance of the graphical or X based solutions are likely to be similar to `teamviewer` or `vnc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vinagre, with the vino package installed on the remote machine.

```
$ sudo apt-get install vinagre

$ sudo apt-get install vino
```